# Creating application forms without border, but with shadow (in Windows Vista&Windows 7)

Tags: winforms, delphi, winapi, windows-vista

How to do that in WinForms?

Comment: Thanks guys, but this not what I want.

If someone will need the same: (C++)
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/FrameShadow.aspx

Comment: There is rather different from what you asked for - shows how important is to write good thorough questions here.

Answer (score 5):

In Delphi you will need to override CreateParams procedure of the form you want to make borderless and add CS_DROPSHADOW ($00020000) style to the defaults.

```
procedure TForm1.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;

  Params.WindowClass.Style := Params.WindowClass.Style or CS_DROPSHADOW;
end;
```

Comment: This will not add aero shadow, this will add popup window shadow. Aero shadow differs for active and for inactive window, `CS_DROPSHADOW` shadow are same all the time and looks different.